# SMOTETomek - how to set ratio as dictionary for fixed balance

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, data-science

I've tried to use this technique to correct very imbalanced classes.

My data set has classes e.g.:

```
In [123]:
data['CON_CHURN_TOTAL'].value_counts()

Out[123]:
0    100
1     10
Name: CON_CHURN_TOTAL, dtype: int64
```

I wanted to use SMOTETomek to under sample 0-class and over sample 1-class to achieve ratio 80 : 20. However, I cannot find a way to correct the dictionary. Of course in full code the ratio 80:20 will be calculated based on number of rows.

When I am trying:

```
from imblearn.combine import SMOTETomek
smt = SMOTETomek(ratio={1:20, 0:80})
```

I have error:

> ValueError: With over-sampling methods, the number of samples in a
>   class should be greater or equal to the original number of samples.
>   Originally, there is 100 samples and 80 samples are asked.

But this method should be suitable for doing both under and over sampling at the same time.

Unfortunately the [documentary](http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/imbalanced-learn/stable/generated/imblearn.combine.SMOTETomek.html) is not working now due to 404 error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've encountered problem with it again, therefore I asked the question directly on imbalanced-learn github.

Here is full answer: [github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/imbalanced-learn](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/imbalanced-learn/issues/552#issuecomment-466348310)

Most important:

> `SMOTETomek` is not doing what you are thinking about.
>
> SMOTETomek applies SMOTE followed by removing the Tomek link and not
>   both over-sampling and under-sampling at the same time.
>
> Be aware that you cannot define the number of samples to use when
>   using Tomek:
>   http://imbalanced-learn.org/en/stable/under_sampling.html#tomek-s-links
>
> If you really want to have an under-sampling you could pipeline 2 samplers:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
import pandas as pd
from imblearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE
from imblearn.under_sampling import NearMiss

data = load_breast_cancer()
X = pd.DataFrame(data=data.data, columns=data.feature_names)

count_class_0 = 300
count_class_1 = 300
pipe = make_pipeline(
    SMOTE(sampling_strategy={0: count_class_0}),
    NearMiss(sampling_strategy={1: count_class_1}
)

X_smt, y_smt = pipe.fit_resample(X, data.target)
```

Comment: Sorry what is count_class meant to do ? why 300 ? @mateusz